# Problema con teclado 4x3 arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino, teclado

estoy realizando un teclado 4x3 para un sistema de control de acceso. El problema que presento es que cuando presiono una tecla por primera vez en el teclado, la tecla presionada se muestra correctamente en serial, pero si vuelvo a presionar otra no se muestra. ¿Me falta algo en el circuito? ¿Le falta algo a mi programación? Agradezco la ayuda, gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
const char keys[4][3] = {
  {'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'7','8','9'},
  {'*','0','#'}
};
const byte rowPins[4] = {13, 12, 11, 10};
const byte colPins[3] = {9, 8, 7};
byte i, j;

void setup(){
    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        pinMode(rowPins[i], OUTPUT);
    }

    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
        pinMode(colPins[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
    }
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
 
void loop(){
    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        // Envíamos un 0 lógico por cada fila.
        digitalWrite(rowPins[i], LOW);
        // Leemos todas las columnas.
        for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
            // Si se detecta que alguna columna recibió el 0 lógico, indica que el botón que comparte la fila y la columna fue presionado.
            if (!digitalRead(colPins[j])){
                Serial.print("Key: ");
                Serial.println(keys[i][j]);
                while(digitalRead(!colPins[j])); // Antirrebote
            }
        }
        // Vuelve a colocar la fila en 1 lógico.
        digitalWrite(rowPins[i], HIGH);
    }
    delay(10);
}
```

Comment: `while(digitalRead(!colPins[j]));` Tienes mal puesta la negación. Estas negando el pin, debe negar la lectura: `while(!digitalRead(colPins[j]));`

Comment: También te falta mandar un HIGH a los rowPins en el setup().

Comment: Muchas gracias, sos un genio, ya funciona. No me había dado cuenta.

Comment: ¿Por qué debo mandar un HIGH a los rowPins?

Comment: Pones los pines en HIGH para detectar cual fue presionado. Tienen que estar en HIGH a la partida.

Comment: Ah ok, gracias de nuevo.